# Need to preload and include an html file

Tags: jquery

Hi I am working on a site that uses server side includes to get content for the page. The problem is that I am developing on my local machine without the server code, so I need to do the includes temporally with jquery. The problem I am having is that the equal height columns script I am using is executing before the include script loads. The result is that I am getting a incorrect heights. How can I solve this?

JS-

```
/*******************************/
/*  JQUERY INCLUDE FILE
/*******************************/
$(window).load(function () { 
    $(".js-include").each(function(){
    var inc=$(this);
        $.get(inc.attr("title"), function(data){
            inc.replaceWith(data);
        });
    });    
});

/*******************************/
/*  EQUAL HEIGHT COLUMNS
/*******************************/
$(document).ready(function() {
   var maxHeight = -1;

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
   });

   $('.equal').each(function() {
     $(this).height(maxHeight);
   });
 });
```

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="sidebar" class="equal col-md-2">
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                      <i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Office Manager
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/office/index">List Offices</a></li>
                        <!-- TMPL_UNLESS is_agent -->
                        <li><a href="/office/add">Add Offices</a></li>
                        <!-- /TMPL_UNLESS -->
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                      <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Agent Manager
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/agent/index">List Agents</a></li>
                        <!-- TMPL_UNLESS is_agent -->
                        <li><a href="/agent/add">Add Agent</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/agent/email">E-mail Agents</a></li>
                        <!-- /TMPL_UNLESS -->
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                      <i class="fa fa-home"></i> Property Manager
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/open_house">Manage Openhouses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/featured_listing/index">Manage Featured Listings</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/slideshow/index">Manage Slideshow Listings</a></li>
                        <!--<li><a href="/property_blast/index">Property Blast™</a></li>-->
                        <li><a href="/virtual_tour/index">Manage Virtual Tours</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                      <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Lead Manager
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/leads/index">Manage Leads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/stats/">Property Statistics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive">
                      <i class="fa fa-users"></i> Client Manager
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/client/index">Contact Directory</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/client/add">Add Client</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/client/email">E-Mail Clients</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
                      <i class="fa fa-h-square"></i> Help
                    </a>
                  </h4>
                </div>
                <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li><a href="/content/manual.html">On-line Manual</a></li>
                        <!-- <li><a href="/support/faq">Frequently Asked Questions</a></li> -->
                        <li><a href="/support">Support Request</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="component" class="equal col-md-9">
            <!-- TMPL_VAR content ESCAPE=0 -->
            <div class="js-include" title="index.html"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to use equal heights script on window(load) too.

Comment: This should help...https://api.jquery.com/on/, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ Because of dynamic content loading, you will need to use event delegation...